# Apache as proxy for ALL files

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I am trying to configure apache to act as a proxy for certain sub-domains. I have almost got it configured, but there is a problem.

With this config, I have managed to get www.mywebsite.com to be served normally (no proxy / default apache config) whilst having subdomain.mywebsite.com served via proxy to localhost port 8080. The problem I am having, is that requests to files other than index.html get proxy error 502.

```
ServerAdmin subdomain@mywebsite.com
ServerName subdomain.mywebsite.com

DocumentRoot "/opt/www/subdomain"

<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

How can I configure apache to serve ALL files via proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite see how what you posted does what you want. But my understanding of the question may be wrong. I understand you want to have:

1. www.mywebsite.com serve pages from "/opt/www/subdomain"
2. subdomain.mywebsite.com serve pages from a backend server running on port 8080.

Therefore you simply need this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/www/subdomain"
  ServerName www.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.mywebsite.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

One difference in the ProxyPass lines to what you have is that I have a trailing slash to match the right side of the directive.